# Use startup application to run project file of QT creator

Tags: startup-applications, qt-creator

I am using Ubuntu 18 and want to run a project(created using QT Creator) when Ubuntu starts up.
I have used startup application to add any program that will run when we start Ubuntu.But I don't know how to run a project of QT creator that can show the direct output window after starting Ubuntu.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: The QtCreator should have made a directory like this : "build-your_project_name-debug" in the parent directory of your project. Go there and there should be a binary with the name of your project(exact same name and without extensions) . Add the address of that binary to the startup applications and you're done.

Comment: Thankyou @ParsaMousavi It worked :)

Answer (score 0):

The `QtCreator` should have made a directory like this :

```
build-your_project_name-[debug or release or profile]
```

in the parent directory of your project. Go there and there should be a binary with the name of your project(exact same name and without extensions) . Add the address of that binary to the startup applications and you're done.